# Can't debug in web express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have following configuration

Vista home premium

iis7

studio web 2008 express edition

trying to debug asp.net 3.5 application. But if try debug it with f5, application runs but debug does not start. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using location to not allow child to inherit config and studio didn't like it. Removing location tag fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this article: [Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/)
And this: [Fix problems with Visual Studio F5 debugging of ASP.NET applications on IIS7 Vista](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/12/28/Fix-problems-with-Visual-Studio-F5-debugging-of-ASP.NET-applications-on-IIS7-Vista.aspx)